# Numbers written in both forms

Tags: number-theory

I have come across the OEIS series [A031363](http://oeis.org/A031363). It has this description:

> Positive numbers of the form $x^2+xy-y^2$; or, of the form $5x^2-y^2$.

So it is saying that all numbers that can be written in the form $x^2+xy-y^2$ can be written as $5x^2-y^2$.

I am a beginner at Number Theory, so any tips or hints on how to proof it would be great.

EDIT: I have done a tiny computer search on it, and confirmed that all numbers (< 10000) that can be written in the first form can also be written in the second form. So it is saying that both form is identical.

Comment: Or is it just saying that the sequence is the union of the sets of the numbers of these forms?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown If so, the semicolon is very strange.

Comment: Have you looked through the links provided on the site?

Comment: @SK19 What do you mean?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Both forms are identical. Please read the edit.

Comment: On the OEIS site, there is a category called "Links". There you can look up research related to these sequences. On another note: Proving that number $n$ up to some specific $N$ that is representable as $x^2+xy-y^2$ is also representable as $5x^2-y^2$ doesn't show the converse and also doesn't show that the forms are identical for all $N$.

Comment: I think this is actually a pretty good question! The two expressions of course give different answers for a fixed pair $(x,y)$, but it seems like for every pair there is another pair that solves the other equation! For example, if we plug in $x=y=2$ in the first expression, the second gets the same value if $x= -233 $ and $y= -521 $. Tricky ...

Comment: Initial idea: If $x$ is even, that is $x=2a$, then $$x^2 + xy - y^2 = 4a^2 + 2ay - y^2 = 5a^2 - (a-y)^2$$. EDIT: upon further thought this says that every number of the latter form is necessarily of the former form, but not necessarily the reverse yet.

Comment: Also, a good strategy for generating some sort of pattern: you've already generated a lot of test cases, and presumably have pairs $(x,y)$ for the first form that correspond to pairs $(x,y)$ for the second form. Why not plot these values and see if there is a simple (say, linear, as my previous comment suggests) relationship?

Comment: Sure. @BobKrueger

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If one of $x$, $y$ is even, WLOG let $x = 2a$.
Same as what [Bob Krueger](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/228620/bob-krueger) said, $x^2 + xy - y^2 = 5a^2 - (a-y)^2$

If both $x$ and $y$ are odd, then $x + y$ and $x + 3y$ are even.
We can check $x^2 + xy - y^2 = 5\left(\frac{x + y}{2}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{x + 3y}{2}\right)^2$

Comment: Inverting the last transformation, we find that $$5u^2-v^2=(3u-v)^2+(3u-v)(v-u)-(v-u)^2$$ so that the converse holds too.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see how this works when $y$ is even.  If $y=2a,$ I get $$x^2+2ax-4a^2=2x^2-(2a-x)^2,$$ and I don't see how to put in the the required form.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that there is a case missing in the accepted answer.  I don't see how we can take $x=2a$ "without loss of generality," because the form $x^2+xy-y^2$ is not symmetric in $x$ and $y.$  Indeed, when $y=2a,$ we have $x^2+xy-y^2 = x^2+2ax-4a^2=2x^2-(2a-x)^2,$ and I don't see how to put this in the required form.

However, when $y$ is even, we have $$5\left(x-\frac{y}{2}\right)^2-\left(2x-\frac{3y}{2}\right)^2=x^2+xy-y^2,$$

so the theorem is true is this case too.

As I noted in a comment on the accepted answer, the identity
$$5u^2-v^2=(3u-v)^2+(3u-v)(v-u)-(v-u)^2$$
establishes the converse.