# Proving that this is true for all x in the sequence.

Tags: number-theory

TL;DR -

> **Is it true, and *how* should I prove that for all $t$ that can be expressed as $u^2+uv-v^2$ for some $u, v \in \Bbb{Z}$, $$\frac{x^2+xy+y^2}{xy-t} = 4$$ has a pair of solution $(x, y) \in \Bbb{N}^2$?**

After reading [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1478289/find-the-integer-values-of-c?rq=1), I have tried to generalize the question by replacing the $1$ in the denominator by $t$, i.e. on

$$\frac{x^2+xy+y^2}{xy-t} = c.$$

I focused on the different possible non-negative integer values for $c$ (for $x, y$ $\in$ $\Bbb{N}$). Then I run a 'tiny' computer search. Here's the result:

[image: Showing possible values of c when t is 1-25]

I observed that there is a lot of $4$s in the arrays, so I filtered them out:

[image]

So here is my result: when t is in the list below, $4$ is a possible value of $c$:
`[1, 4, 5, 9, 11, 16, 19, 20, 25, 29, 31, 36, 41, 44, 45, 49, 55, 59, 61, 64, 71, 76, 79, 80, 81, 89, 95, 99]`

Doing a simple OEIS search gives us the sequence [A031363](http://oeis.org/A031363).

And checking for all values in the OEIS sequence up to 10k, they all give $4$ as a possible value for $c$.

So here is my question after all the nonsense story:

> **Is it true, and *how* should I prove that for all $t$ that can be expressed as $u^2+uv-v^2$ for some $u, v \in \Bbb{Z}$, $$\frac{x^2+xy+y^2}{xy-t} = 4$$ has a pair of solution $(x, y) \in \Bbb{N}^2$?**

(This is actually not proven to be true, so I am here to conjecture this.)

Thanks for reading, any tips or hints would be greatly appreciated!

Related: [Number written in both forms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2667082/numbers-written-in-both-forms/2667108#2667108) (Also by me)

Comment: I suppose your question in the TL;DR part is "whether $\frac{x^2 + xy + y^2}{xy - t} = 4$" has a solution rather than "whether $\frac{x^2 + xy + y^2}{xy - t} = c$" has a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any $t \in \mathbb{N}_+$ such that$$
t = u^2 - v^2 + uv
$$
for some $u, v \in \mathbb{N}$, note that $u$ and $v$ cannot be $0$ simultaneously, then take$$
(x, y) = (2u + 2v, 2u),
$$
and$$
\frac{x^2 + xy + y^2}{xy - t} = \frac{12u^2 + 4v^2 + 12uv}{4u^2 + 4uv - t} = 4.
$$

Answer (score 3):

The direction you ask about at the end is straightforward. 
$$ x^2 + xy + y^2 = 4xy - 4 t \; , $$
$$ x^2 - 3 x y + y^2 = -4 t.   $$
The quadratic form $x^2 - 3 xy + y^2$ has discriminant $ 9 - 4 = 5.$ This means it is integrally equivalent to the other for you ask about, as $h(5) = 1.$  Indeed, if we take the (integer invertible) change of variables
$$ x = p + 2 q \; , \; \;  y = q \; , $$
$$ x^2 - 3 xy + y^2 = p^2 + pq - q^2.  $$
Next, with $p^2 + pq - q^2 = -4 t,$ we cannot get an even number unless both $p,q$ are even. Let $r=p/2, \; \; s = q/2, \;$ we get
$$ r^2 + rs - s^2 = -t. $$
We can also multiply by $-1$ easily enough. We take $u = s, \; v = r+s, \;$ we get
$$  u^2 + uv - v^2 = t \; .  $$